# How to tell the difference between lydian mode and dorian mode in songs

Tags: modes, analysis

I am writing a song progression using the lydian mode using AABA form. My chord progression will be

- A: E F# A E
- A: E F# A E
- B: C#m F# A E
- A: E F# A E

The scale for the melody is E major pentatonic so no clues there....

The A sections are clearly in lydian mode but my question relates to the B section chord progression. Since this phrase starts in C#m now should I see this phrase as being in dorian mode with the F# major chord as the IV of dorian or have we never left lydian mode?

Comment: Not sure which chords are major or minor!

Comment: Your title references the mixolydian mode but there is no mention of this in the question, but rather the lydian mode. "Since this phrase starts in C#m" - excuse me? All the chords appear to be major chords, so where does the minor come from? Dorian is a minor mode with a raised sixth, whereas lydian is a major mode with a raised fourth.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question, please forgiveme... very sloppy

Comment: It's not in any mode at all. It's not Lydian, Mixolydian, Dorian, any mode. How can I tell? First of all, it _sounds_ like it's making a chromatic alteration. Secondly, it _is_ making a chromatic alteration. In the F# major chord, there is an A#, it's the third of the chord. But in the A major chord, there is an A natural. When you do chromatic alterations, you don't call it a mode. Maybe you could call it _modal interchange_ or something. The F# major chord first sounds like a secondary dominant going to B, but the expected motion is not fulfilled - you use an A chord instead.

Comment: Piiperi, the A section is Lydian mode. the #4 is what gives the mode its charecteristic sound. Chromatic alterations are valid but say nothing of what something sounds like. To me, chromatic alteration is not as specific as saying that we hear "lydian mode" The lydian mode has a flavor to it, a certain sound. What is a major scale with a raised 4th degree? It is the lydian scale and it has a certain sound to it.. if all raised #4 and b7 degrees in major are chromatic alterations, then there is no such thing as a modes

Comment: @armani The #4 and b7 "chromatic alterations" have to be consistent, *to the point that ♮4 and ♮7 are never used in the piece/section*, in order for the piece/section to be modal. A piece that uses E-F-F#-G-A-B-C-D isn't modal. (The 2+ semitone spans in a row already give that away.)

Comment: I don't see why from a theory perspective you can't say that the modal sound is as temporary as a chromatic alteration, at the very least both should be valid..Can you please refer to the document I posted to Aaron, curious to hear what you think

Comment: Your A chord is not diatonic to E Lydian. It uses the P4 not the #4 of the Lydian scale. The 4 chord in Lydian is a #IVdim or m7b5.

Comment: @armani The page you linked says "A modal schema may be used without a pop song being entirely strictly within that mode." So you'd like to say that your song "uses a _modal schema_"? I don't know, I've never heard about "modal schemas". What I have heard someone sometimes say is that they e.g. briefly use a Lydian sound. But in this E - F# - A - E progression the F# is so short and gets completely bulldozed by the A, I don't get Lydian feelings at all, it sounds like some rock tune I heard 30 years ago. Things you can make up by moving your hand to different positions on the guitar fretboard.

Answer (score 1):

Modal pieces emphasize the scale degrees that differentiate that mode from major and minor. A lydian piece will emphasize the #4, and a dorian piece will emphasize the #6.

This means the B section is not dorian.

1. The melody, being pentatonic, avoids the #6 entirely.
2. The harmony includes the natural-6, specifically in the third chord, effectively eliminating — or cancelling out — any prior use of the #6.

In fact, the A section is not lydian either, for similar reasons.

1. The melody, being pentatonic, avoids the #4 entirely.
2. The harmony is so strongly rooted in E major — between both the chords and the melody — that the brief appearance of the #4 sounds like a simple chromatic alteration to major rather than true lydian.

Comment: Aaron, harmonic progressions can still have the necessary degree altered to conform to the mode without any need for a melody to have the note in it. When it is in the melody as well however, it is heard more strongly but a progression of chords can still be in a mode without the melody needing to stray away from a pentatonic scale. your term "true lydian" I don't think I understand it. Could you explain how this might be "true lydian" what would need to change?

Comment: Please refer to this page https://viva.pressbooks.pub/openmusictheory/chapter/modal-schemas/ where the author discusses my progression as being in the Lydian mode. It is even called a "Lydian cadence"

Comment: @armani I completely disagree with that author's analysis. There's nothing lydian about the cadence described. It's major with a chord that happens to be from a secondary key. By "true lydian", I mean "truly in the lydian mode".

Comment: @armani I guess it's worth pointing out that the author herself acknowledges that the IV chord immediately undermines the use of the #4 in the previous chord.

Comment: @armani As Aaron writes, I think the confusion is here that she mentions that #4 brings the sound of lydian, but this does not equate to the melody or the progression being in lydian mode.

Comment: I thought that the "sound of lydian" is Lydian mode. I think the confusion comes from me seeing the lydian mode as a temporary sound within a greater framework of harmonic progression while you guys are saying that it must be Lydian from beginning to end for it to be called lydian mode but in music I listen to, nothing is written entirely in lydian mode from beginning to end and I don't know if in classical music it is because i don't really listen to much classical music.  Could you point to just one piece of popular music that is in lydian mode?

Comment: @armani It's certainly possible for a passage of a larger, non-lydian work to be lydian, but it needs to be a substantial enough passage to convincingly establish the "sound of lydian" in the listener's ear.

Comment: @armani A more familiar example would be the use of a secondary dominant. For a piece in C major, one could have the chord progression C - Dmaj - G - D. Nobody would argue for lydian at the D major; it would just be interpreted as a secondary dominant. On the other hand, C - D - C - D - C - D, especially with a supporting melody which uses the F# over the C chord, could very well me interpreted as lydian.

Comment: @armani The Simpsons theme uses the Lydian mode. First it's C Lydian, then it switches to B Lydian, then to E Lydian, etc. It does diverge from Lydian in the end with a flat 7th.

Comment: piiperi, simpsons theme uses the Lydian Dominant scale, is that why you think ot diverges from Lydian mode?

Comment: @armani I found that claim on the internet as well. IMO it does not use a flat 7th so prominently that such a distinction is needed. Saying "lydian" is enough and it describes the sound of the theme well. I said it diverges because there's a flat 7th in the end. "It does diverge from Lydian in the end _with a flat 7th._" After that there's _also_ a major 7th. Music theory is descriptions of music, from some perspective, for some purpose. What is your purpose? In what situation does calling the Simpsons theme Lydian ruin or harm what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @armani Wasn't it the whole point of the article you linked to, that you can utilize modal patterns, without every part of the entire piece having to perfectly follow some theoretical model? If you feel that for your purpose, it is useful to see a harmonic pattern that has a name in music theory, go ahead. But there are other views and different purposes. I mean, if you can really hear a Lydian sound during the E - F# chord pair, and it benefits your song, go ahead, it's OK. Personally, I can't find a useful way to think of it as Lydian, but if you can, it's OK.

Comment: I really can and I think many people see it my way. It isnt a personal thing of mine alone. Being as experienced about music you should acknowledge different schools of thought. We all should. The more I learn about music the more I realize is that one can see things in different ways so I am going to try keep an open mind as I go.

Answer (score 0):

I thought modes referred to the melody rather than harmony, so if you're using E pent. major, you're still using that all through. But if you want it modal, the melody had better 'home' on the roots that make those modes.